# How to remove a (session) cookie in Play Framework 2.5.x /Java

Tags: java, cookies, playframework, session-cookies

I am using Play 2.5.3. I want to remove a session-cookie when user did some specific actions.

My cookie is like this.

`// Cookie:  name, value, maximum age, path, domain, secure, http only`
`Cookie("name", somestring, null, "/", somedomain, false, false)`

I have already tried what Play documents showed.

`request().discardCookie(name, path, domain)`

Turns out it doesn't work. What should I try next.
Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

You need to use

```
response().discardCookie("name");
```

Answer (score 2):

in scala you need to pass `DiscardingCookie` instance as follows:
`response.discardingCookies(DiscardingCookie("cookie_name"))`

see maybe similar class is available in Java api.

Answer (score 1):

As of play 2.8, Http.Context got discontinued. You can now instead use

```
return ok().discardingCookies("COOKIE_NAME");
```

So basically any changes to the response needs to be applied to the result object your function returns directly, instead of interacting with the old response() method.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use

```
response.removeCookie(keyName);
```

Comment: I tried but this version of Play or play.mvc.HTTP package does not support the syntax.

Answer (score 0):

```
Cookie c = new Cookie("name", "", 0, somepath, somedomain, false, false);
return ok().withCookies(c);
```

It turns out, ↑ works out.

Try to set the value to "", and the maxAge to 0.
Set **everything else what they were**.

The new cookie should replace the old one. And vanished since the maxAge is 0.

Hope this could help someone. Lol

Comment: Its better to use `response().discardCookie("name");` rather putting cookie maxAge attr.